# Не могу открыть файл в python

Tags: python-3.x

```
f = open("D:\positive.txt")
r = f.read()
print(r)
```

Получается вот такой стек ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/perforce/Social/test4.py", line 2, in <module>
    r = f.read()
  File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 11943: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: попробуйте `f = open("D:\positive.txt", encoding='utf-8')`

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open("D:\positive.txt", encoding='utf-8')
r = f.read()
print(r)
```